# How to terminate Eloquent chunking from closure

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, chunking

Using Eloquent, how can I terminate chunking based on a condition within the `chunk` function's closure? I've tried returning, but that seems to terminate only the current chunk and not all chunking. At this point, I want to stop retrieving records from the database.

```
$query->chunk(self::CHUNK_SIZE, function ($objects) {
    if (someCondition) {
        // terminate chunking here
        return;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you `return false` it will break.
If you are in a `do while` loop and `return` anything it will exit the loop. In the source code below you can see:

```
        if ($callback($results) === false) {
            return false;
        }
```

which gives you an opportunity to exit out.

```
 /**
     * Chunk the results of the query.
     *
     * @param  int  $count
     * @param  callable  $callback
     * @return bool
     */
    public function chunk($count, callable $callback)
    {
        $this->enforceOrderBy();
        $page = 1;
        do {
            // We'll execute the query for the given page and get the results. If there are
            // no results we can just break and return from here. When there are results
            // we will call the callback with the current chunk of these results here.
            $results = $this->forPage($page, $count)->get();
            $countResults = $results->count();
            if ($countResults == 0) {
                break;
            }
            // On each chunk result set, we will pass them to the callback and then let the
            // developer take care of everything within the callback, which allows us to
            // keep the memory low for spinning through large result sets for working.
            if ($callback($results) === false) {
                return false;
            }
            $page++;
        } while ($countResults == $count);
        return true;
    }
```

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.php#L18

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately it doesn't like `break`. "Cannot break/continue 1 level."

Comment: edited my answer after looking further into it, seems you just need to return false

Comment: Thanks! That did what I needed it to do.